# c \ c++ conversion to C#

Tags: c++, c

how do i convert the following struct into c#? Do the brackets following the types indicate an array or how much memory to put aside for each value?

```
typedef struct Cake{
    uint8          sysnulls_[2];
    char           Pie[21];
    uint8          MuffinCount[10];
    uint8          NumOfCookies[6];
} Cake;
```

Comment: `c \ c++` is invalid, if you meant `c / c++` that's UB.

Comment: and please, google for _array_.

Comment: You are close. This is the number of elements of each array (which may be each more than a single byte). C# has arrays, right?

Comment: Thanks immibis! one more question if you dont mind. would sysnulls be 1 16 byte integer? so for example maybe it could hold a value of 800000 or whatever or would it be two integers i.e. 88 like the array of characters is im guessing a string?

clear as mud?

Comment: I think you mean bit, not byte.  And it's an array of 2 uint8s.  You can do all sorts of weird and fun stuff with casting, but that's clearly not the intent here.  If you want a unit16, then that's what you'd say.

Comment: Yes it has arrays, but you also declare strings not char[50] :) so i guess more what i am interested in or maybe a better way of asking my question is what does an array of 2 unsigned 8 bit integers mean? is it to allow for a number of 16 bytes total or is it two distinct 8 bit values (which wouldnt make sense for one property)

Comment: ok thanks guys. this is enough to get me going. appreciate it

Comment: @Muckeypuck How can we guess what it means? Look at the documentation about `Cake`, that should tell you what all the members mean. Also, not every array of chars is a string.

Comment: i have no documentation. i have to figure that out. thanks though for the brilliant idea

Comment: @Muckeypuck: C does not have a string type. It is all convention of the library functions (and the compiler for _string literals_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the number of element in an array, not the number of bytes. So in the structure above, you have

2 int8 sysnulls_ which you can access through:

```
Cake gateaux;

gateaux.sysnulls_[0]; // first one
gateaux.sysnulls_[1]; // second one.
```

While in this instance the `sysnulls_` array does indeed occupy 2 bytes of memory, it is only because each uint8 occupies one byte. So it is important to make a distinction between number of elements and number of bytes.

If you had

```
typedef struct Cake{
    uint16          sysnulls_[2];
    char           Pie[21];
    uint8          MuffinCount[10];
    uint8          NumOfCookies[6];
} Cake;
```

the each `sysnulls_` element would occupy 2 bytes and the total space allocated for the `sysnulls_` array would be 4 bytes.

Furthermore, the size of the structure is **NOT** always equal to the sum of the parts. This is because most compilers will add padding to align each element on either a 2, 4 or 8 byte boundary.

If your compiler used 4 byte alignment, then in your example you would have `sysnulls_` at offset 0. then there would be 2 bytes of space to put `Pie` at offset 4. This brings us to offset 25 at the end of pie. Again the compiler would add another 3 bytes of padding to make sure that `MuffinCount` start at offset 28 (7 x 4). NumOfCookies would start at offset 36 (with a padding 2 before it) and the total structure size would be 44 (rounding up to the nearest multiple of 4).

Most compilers have compiler options to set the default packing and also pragmas to control the packing for a given structure.

Comment: How do you know that `uint16` occupies 2 bytes?

Comment: One byte is 8 bits 16/8 = 2. You can also findout the size with the `sizeof()` operator.

Comment: Ubercoder, this is all good, but what tells you uint16 is 16 bits in size?

Comment: Nothing but about 40 years programming experience. If someone is daft enough to define uint16 as anything other than a 16bit unsigned integer they deserve all the problems that will be coming their way.

Comment: Judging by the comments here maybe there is no way to help (i.e. a uint16 may not neccessarily be an unsigned 16 bit integer) but part of my problem is why would somebody declare numberofcookies as an array of integers?

Maybe thats program specific and im not looking for help with that, i can work that out but in c++ is there anyway an array of 2 integers can represent 1 number?

Comment: Can you do this?  Yes.  However, it obscures the actual meaning and you should assume that if it's declared as an array it's being used as an array.

Answer (score 7):

Your guess is not correct.

All of these members are arrays.
`uint8 sysnulls_[2];` means that `sysnulls_` is an array of 2 `uint8`'s.
Likewise, `char Pie[21];` means that `Pie` is an array of 21 `char`s, and so on.

`uint8` is not a standard C type. Presumably it's an unsigned 8-bit integer, but you should look at how it's defined if you want to be sure.

Comment: The question remains what is `uint8`.

Comment: @SergeyA `uint8` is not a standard C type. Presumably it's an unsigned 8-bit integer, but you should look at how it's defined if you want to be sure.

Comment: You got me right. I was just pointing to exactly this fact.